# Google Cloud Endpoint API works correct but there are no records in log

Tags: google-cloud-endpoints

I use Google Cloud Endpoint API with Google cloud function backend.
I successfully call my functions as defined in the API "swagger" file and see all functions invocations in the cloud function log.
But Endpoint services of Google cloud console shows nothing. Also, there are no records in the endpoint log.
Any idea?

Comment: There is instruction how to track logs for Endpoints for Cloud Functions https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/get-started-cloud-functions#track_api 
Does it not work as well?

Comment: The endpoints request log is empty.

Comment: I will try to recreate your scenario

Comment: You can find logs in Logging section > Produced API > "SERVICE_NAME". Can you please check?

Comment: I found "Logging section > Produced API > "SERVICE_NAME" but there are no records for it

Comment: I recreted this scenario https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/get-started-cloud-functions and I can see all logs here.

Comment: I have five projects and this happens in only for one of them

Comment: It is better to contact Google Cloud support team, since they can check your project.